# How Do I Negate the Statement $ p \implies q$ is $ p \wedge \lnot q $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Statement is: A and C are disjoint

I write as

$ \forall x \in A \implies x \notin C$. So as negation of $ p \implies q$ is $ p \wedge \lnot q $. So I have $ \forall x \in A$ and $  x \in C$. This does not make much sense. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: It should be written $\forall x(x\in A\implies x\notin C)$.

Answer (score 3):

Your task is to negate the formula
$$
\forall x(x\in A\to x\notin C)
$$
which is easy enough: put $\lnot$ in front of it. If you want a more expressive formula, use the fact that $A\to B$ is equivalent to $\lnot A\lor B$ and $\exists x$ is $\lnot \forall x\lnot$:
$$
\lnot\forall x(x\in A\to x\notin C)
\equiv
\lnot\forall x\lnot\lnot(x\notin A\lor x\notin C)
\equiv
\exists x(x\in A\land x\in C)
$$
(also using De Morgan and double negation, of course)

Comment: in third line, how did you write $ A \implies B $ as (not A) or B

Comment: @J.Deff That's a known tautology or the definition of $\to$, depending on the approach.

Comment: @AntoineMathys Where's the problem? Since the negation of the OP's is exactly “$A$ and $C$ are not disjoint” the task is done..

Comment: @AntoineMathys We don't know what's in the OP's toolbox of allowed results and I wouldn't guess.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of "$A$ and $C$ are disjoint" is $$\exists x (x\in A \land x\in C).$$

Comment: How? I think negation of implication doesnot work this way

Comment: Because no implication is necessary. If $A$ and $C$ are not disjoint then there is an $x$ that is in both $A$ and $C$.

Comment: The negation of $p\implies \lnot q$ is $p\land\lnot\lnot q$, which is equivalent to $p\land q$.

Comment: Note that $x\notin C$ is the same as $\lnot (x\in C)$.

Comment: Does that make sense now, @J.Deff?

Comment: what you have written in comment is true, i forgot the brackets. but how to negate that